# Problem with gdk.Pixbuf in gtk# Mono

Tags: mono, gtk#, cairo, gdk, pixbuf

I'm creating a small drawing program in Mono gtk# and using the Cairo graphics library. I'm coding and compiling on a MacOs X system. I have a drawable object which I put into Pixbuf at a certain time and then retrieve it later into the drawable object! The idea is to take a "snapshot" of the image in the drawable and then draw on top of it.

The problem is that when I put the Pixbuf back into the drawable it looks obscure, all yellow with stripes and it looks like a portion of the image is missing.

UPDATE: I ran the program on my linux and windows machines and there it works flawlessly! So this error is only on MacOs X. 
Here's the code:

```
// use: gmcs -pkg:gtk-sharp-2.0 -pkg:mono-cairo ttv1.cs

using Gtk;
using Cairo;
using System;

public class Draw : Window
{   
DrawingArea canvas;

public Gdk.Pixbuf pixbuf;

public Draw() : base("teikniteink")
{
    canvas = new DrawingArea();
    canvas.ExposeEvent += canvasExposed;
    DeleteEvent += delegate { Application.Quit();};

    KeyPressEvent += onKey;
    SetDefaultSize(400,400);
    SetPosition(WindowPosition.Center);
    Add(canvas);
    ShowAll();
}


private void onKey(object o, KeyPressEventArgs args)
{
    switch (args.Event.Key)
    {
        case Gdk.Key.w:
        Console.WriteLine("Key Pressed {0}", args.Event.Key);
        // Send to Pixbuf
        pixbuf = Gdk.Pixbuf.FromDrawable(canvas.GdkWindow, Gdk.Colormap.System,0,0,0,0,400,400);
        // Save to output.png
                    pixbuf.Save ("output.png", "png");  
        break;
        case Gdk.Key.e:
        Console.WriteLine("Key Pressed {0}", args.Event.Key);

        Gdk.GC g = new Gdk.GC(canvas.GdkWindow);
        // Retrive from pixbuf
        canvas.GdkWindow.DrawPixbuf (g,pixbuf,0,0,0,0,-1,-1,Gdk.RgbDither.Normal,0,0);      
        break;
    }
}

private void canvasExposed(object o, ExposeEventArgs args)
{
    using (Cairo.Context ctx = Gdk.CairoHelper.Create(canvas.GdkWindow))
    {
        PointD start = new PointD(100,100);
        PointD end = new PointD(300,300);
        double width = Math.Abs(start.X - end.X);
        double height = Math.Abs(start.Y - end.Y);
        double xcenter = start.X + (end.X - start.X) / 2.0;
        double ycenter = start.Y + (end.Y - start.Y) / 2.0;

        ctx.Save();
        ctx.Translate(xcenter, ycenter);
        ctx.Scale(width/2.0, height/2.0);
        ctx.Arc(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 2*Math.PI);
        ctx.Restore();
        ctx.Stroke();
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    Application.Init();
    new Draw();
    Application.Run();
}
}
```

It would be very much appreciated if someone knows whats going on here and can point me in the right direction to fix it.

Comment: It sounds like you might be taking the wrong approach, but I can't be sure; what is the ultimate goal you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @ptomato The goal is to make a simple scribble program! Where the user can draw rectangles, lines and circles on top of each other and then save the image (and load an image as well). I plan on setting the pixbuf on a onMouseRelease event and reading from the pixbuf to the drawable on an exposeEvent, so what the user will be currently drawing appears on top of the image. I'm new to gtk# and cairo so I might be taking the wrong approach like you say!

Comment: If you ran it on the other platforms and it worked, then the cause is certainly a bug in the OS X port of GTK#. You should file a bug at bugzilla.gnome.org.

Comment: That said, here is a link to a slightly outdated GTK tutorial in C, that does exactly what you are trying to do: http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk-tutorial/2.90/c2417.html ; it looks like they draw directly on the backing store, then queue an update to the drawable.

Comment: Thanks @ptomato , That tutorial seems to have slipped my google-searching fingers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I triggered the same problem in this manner:

```
gw = gtk_widget_get_window(GTK_WIDGET(GLOBALS->mainwindow));
if(gw)
    {       
    gdk_drawable_get_size(gw, &w, &h);
    cm = gdk_drawable_get_colormap(gw);
    if(cm)
            {
            dest = gdk_pixbuf_new(GDK_COLORSPACE_RGB, FALSE, 8, w, h);
            if(dest)
                    {
                    dest2 = gdk_pixbuf_get_from_drawable(dest, gw, cm, 0, 0, 0, 0, w, h);
                    if(dest2)
                            {
                            succ = gdk_pixbuf_save (dest2, *GLOBALS->fileselbox_text, "png", &err, NULL);
                            }
                    }
            }
    }
```

The gdk_pixbuf_get_from_drawable() function when the source drawable is a Quartz window has issues, specifically in how _gdk_quartz_image_copy_to_image() services it.  In short, 256 bit vertical strips are converted but the conversion routine assumes the pixels are 24-bit RGB rather than 32-bit RGBA.  The following patch fixed the problem for me:

```
--- gtk+/gdk/quartz/gdkimage-quartz.c   2011-12-03 14:24:03.000000000 -0600
+++ gtk+664894/gdk/quartz/gdkimage-quartz.c     2013-10-15 18:52:24.000000000 -0500
@@ -150,6 +150,10 @@ _gdk_quartz_image_copy_to_image (GdkDraw
       data = [rep bitmapData];
       size = [rep size];

+      int bpr = [rep bytesPerRow];
+      int wid = size.width;
+      int bpx = bpr/wid;
+
      for (y = 0; y < size.height; y++)
        {
         guchar *src = data + y * [rep bytesPerRow];
@@ -158,12 +162,15 @@ _gdk_quartz_image_copy_to_image (GdkDraw
            {
              gint32 pixel;

+              if (bpx == 4) // fix gdk_pixbuf_get_from_drawable "yellow stripes"
+                pixel = src[0] << 16 | src[1] << 8 | src[2];
+              else
              if (image->byte_order == GDK_LSB_FIRST)
                pixel = src[0] << 8 | src[1] << 16 |src[2] << 24;
              else
                pixel = src[0] << 16 | src[1] << 8 |src[2];

-             src += 3;
+             src += bpx;

              gdk_image_put_pixel (image, dest_x + x, dest_y + y, pixel);
            }
```

I don't know if this was fixed in future versions of the GTK OSX source.  I use my own for producing binaries of gtkwave as I have some necessary patches that were seemingly never integrated into the jhbuild source tree long ago.

-Tony